# Meteor: Forcing rerendering whole template after collection update with Blaze

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a template in which the DOM is changed, and I would like to rerender the template when saving to database. Before Blaze, Meteor would have rerendered the whole template if there was a reactive variable somewhere in the template, but now how can I do this ?

I have a collection of *clips* set up in an Iron router route :

```
ClipsController = RouteController.extend({
    data: function() {
      clips = Clips.find({}, {sort: {created: 1}});
      return {clips: clips};
    }
});
```

And a template for *clips* :

```
<template name="clips">
  {{#each clips}}
    {{> clip}}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Then, I have a template for *clip* :

```
<template name="clip">
  <article class="clip" id="{{_id}}">
    {{{content}}}
    <ul class="tags">
      {{#each tags}}
        <li><a href="/#{{this}}">#{{this}}</a></li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </article>
</template>
```

And a script for this template which changes the DOM and then saves the *clip* :

```
Template.clip.events({
  'click .edit': function(event, template) {
    template.$('.tags li').each(function() {
      $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/^#(.*)/, "$1"));
    });
  },

  'click .save': function(event, template) {
    var data = {
      //...
    };

    Clips.update({_id: this._id}, data);

    // How to rerender the template ?
  }
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't believe that Blaze provides any way to rerender the entire template as the point of Blaze is to have fine grained updates.

A quick and dirty way to achieve this might be to use Session, a template helper, and an {{#unless}} block that wraps the whole template and then just set the Session key to true before the update and false after causing everything in the {{#unless}} block to rerender.

```
Template.clips.noRender = function(){
  return Session.get("noRender");
}

Template.clip.events({
  'click .edit': function(event, template) {
    template.$('.tags li').each(function() {
      $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/^#(.*)/, "$1"));
    });
  },

  'click .save': function(event, template) {
    var data = {
      //...
    };

    Session.set("noRender", true);

    Clips.update({_id: this._id}, data, function(){
      Session.set("noRender", false);
    });

    // How to rerender the template ?
  }
});

<template name="clips">
  {{#unless noRender}}
    {{#each clips}}
      {{> clip}}
    {{/each}}
  {{/unless}}
</template>
```

Comment: That's clever ! In my own case, using a slightly different template for editing / viewing and dynamically switching the template did the trick, but this is a good trick.

Comment: Clever, terrible, but so damn useful. :)

Comment: What @AdamMoisa said. Clever, terrible, but so damn useful.

Answer (score 2):

I think this might be a better solution also the meteor way.

```
../clips.js

Template.clips.onRendered(function(){

   this.autorun(function(){
     Template.currentData();
   });

});
```

> **template.autorun(runFunc)**
>
> You can use this.autorun from an onCreated or onRendered callback to
>   reactively update the DOM or the template instance. You can use
>   Template.currentData() inside of this callback to access reactive data
>   context of the template instance.
>
> http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_autorun

Answer (score 1):

Blaze provides an easy way to do this:

```
var template = Template.instance();
var parentDom = /*where to put your Template*/;
Blaze.remove(template.view);
Blaze.render(Template.clips, parentDom);
```

What it does is it removes your invalid Template and renders a new one as child.
http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/blaze_remove 
http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/blaze_render

Answer (score 0):

iron-router data action is reactive default.

```
   clips = Clips.find({}, {sort: {created: 1}});
```

replace to

```
  clips = Clips.find({}, {sort: {created: 1}}).fetch();
```

Comment: Both seem to work the same, or am I missing something ?

Comment: The first one returns a cursor (which is a Meteor object), the other gives you an array with results.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but why would I return an array instead of a cursor in that case ?

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way is to use [`Tracker.afterFlush`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_afterflush).

For example:

```
Tracker.autorun ->
    Tracker.afterFlush ->
        # DOM is updated, why don't you do something here?
```