# How should I make sure that a reactive DOM element has been loaded?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars, meteor-helper

I have a template `image` where I display images. The image display toggles between `canvas` and `img` tags, depending on if the user just created the image or if it is already on server.

I toogle between `img` and `canvas` using a reactive dictionary called `pageSession` where I store a boolean reactive variable called `displayMode`. I have an helper `currentDisplayMode` used to return `displayMode` value.

So the helper looks like this:

```
Template.image.helpers({
    "currentDisplayMode" : function(){
        return pageSession.get ("displayMode");
    }
});
```

and in my template, I load the `canvas` or the `img` depending on `currentDisplayMode` like this:

```
{{#if currentDisplayMode}}
  <img src="{{source}}"width="215" height="215"/>
{{else}}
  <canvas id="canvas" width="215" height="215"></canvas>
{{/if}}
```

**1. the problem**.

If I try something like this:

```
pageSession.set("displayMode", false)
var canvas = template.find('#canvas')
//do stuff related to canvas
```

I can't find my canvas because the UI isn't updated yet.

**2. My dirty fix**

I use a `Meteor.setTimeout()` like this to fix it:

```
    pageSession.set("displayMode", false)
    Meteor.setTimeout(function(){
        var canvas = template.find('#canvas')
        //do stuff related to canvas
        }, 100);
```

**3. My question**

This fix works so far but I'm worried about cases where 100ms wouldn't be enough to update the UI. Moreover, I don't feel like it is a reliable solution.

*Note that it is not just a binary toggle (image or canvas)*. The canvas need to be re-rendered depending on 3 different modes (identicon, photo, imageFile). Each mode can be re-rendered as well.

To sum it up, I need to fill properly my canvas in several cases (once I make sure it has been rendered before):

- when `displayMode` toogles: from `<img>` to `<canvas>`
- when I fill my canvas with another method: from identicon to photo for instance
- when I fill my canvas with the same method, but different data: e.g. I reload another identicon or I load another photo.
  How would you proceed?

I tried two other approaches, both by moving the canvas into a dedicated template:

- `Blaze.render()` the template in a target div and attach to the canvas template `rendered` function my code. It makes it difficult to control what is or what isn't loaded: I need to remove previously rendered canvas templates.
- the workaround explained here: [Meteor: Forcing rerendering whole template after collection update with Blaze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23355878/meteor-forcing-rerendering-whole-template-after-collection-update-with-blaze) did not work either (I haven't tried hard, it does not look like a clean workaround).

Comment: Why can't you run the stuff that you want to run after `pageSession.set("displayMode", false)` inside the `template.MyCanvas.onRendered` hook? That way you wouldn't have to do anything weird with scoping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this. Basically, what I wanted was to be sure that my canvas was rendered before doing one of my 3 filling tasks (identicon, photo, imageFile).

The first step is the easy one: I use a page Session reactive variable flag `canvasLoaded` that I update on my `rendered` and `destroyed` canvas template functions.

The second step is something I already used to make sure a file was uploaded (and its url available) on form submit. This is a `waitfor` function I found here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14811679/3793161

So what I do is to wait for my flag `canvasLoaded` to switch to true in the `waitfor` function. In the callback of `waitfor` I just call a `loadCanvas` function where I load the canvas according to the current filling mode and parameters (all stored in reactive dictionary variables).

Et voilà! :-)