# How do I run client-side code after a new collection item has been added to a Meteor view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

In my template, I call a server-side method to add an item to a collection. This collection is displayed on the page. Once the new item is rendered, I want to focus it for the user.

Here's the helper that fires the server method.

```
'click .add-post-button': function(e) {
  var userId = Template.parentData(0)._id;
  Meteor.call('addPost', userId, function(error, result) {
    Session.set('newPostId', result);
  });
}
```

Once this is finished, the new item appears. I want to focus it for the user. Previously, I tried to do it in the callback above with jQuery, but that didn't work because it had not been added to the DOM by the time the callback ran. Now, I'm trying to use the rendered callback:

```
Template.postsAdmin.rendered = function() {
  var newPostId = Session.get('newPostId');
  if (newPostId) {
    var $newPostCell = $('#' + newPostId);
    $newPostCell.find('.post').focus();
  }
};
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be working either. This code does not run when the new item is added to the view.

How can I run code after the new item has been added to the view in order to focus the new item?

Comment: Did you check `result`?

Comment: @Billybobbonnet Yes. Result is returning the post ID as expected.

Comment: Sorry for asking, but just in case: you checked that your rendered callback is executed *after* the `Session` var is filled? Just to make sure you are using the right `rendered`

Comment: @Billybobbonnet No need to apologize! In fact, the rendered function is *not* firing. I put a breakpoint in it, and I never get there. I'm confused as to why.

Comment: I did something similar a while ago and I ended up putting the jquery logic in the callback, as you said you already tried. I too had the same problem of the new item not being in the DOM at first, so I put the jQuery code inside a timeout function with a 200ms delay and that worked. Absolutely  not the most elegant way of doing it, but it was fine for me since it was a pet project.

Comment: have a look at my topic mentioned in the @David Weldon answer. I did the same thing than you, tried a more robust solution, and discovered in his answer a better one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original code is really close - you just need to put the focus logic into a reactive context so it will run again with the session variable changes. The shortest path to success is to use a [template autorun](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_autorun):

```
Template.postsAdmin.onRendered(function() {
  this.autorun(function() {
    var newPostId = Session.get('newPostId');
    if (newPostId) {
      var $newPostCell = $('#' + newPostId);
      return $newPostCell.find('.post').focus();
    }
  });
});
```

---

However, one problem you may run into is that you'll have a race condition where the new post is added **after** the autorun fires. A hacky solution is to add a timeout to the above. An improved solution is to add something like your original code to the `onRendered` callback of the newly added post sub-template:

```
Template.post.onRendered(function() {
  var newPostId = Session.get('newPostId');
  if (newPostId === this.data._id) {
    // add code here to focus this template instance
  }
});
```

Comment: I am not sure to understand, and I see an opportunity to learn something -> I assumed that the `rendered` function is fired whenever a DOM element changes or is added/removed. Could you confirm that it is not the case? And could you also confirm if when using `template.autorun()`, all it takes to make it run again is changing a Session var inside it, (or a reactive var or reactive dict)? Thanks, as always, for your knowledge, David.

Comment: (1) `onRendered` now fires only once when the template instance is first added to the page. It does not fire again when its child DOM elements change. (2) Yes, you only need a single reactive variable to change inside of a reactive context (an autorun in this case) in order to cause a rerun.

Comment: Many thanks. I am glad I understood this. Now I will not waste time like I did on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31076359/how-should-i-make-sure-that-a-reactive-dom-element-has-been-loaded?noredirect=1#comment50172431_31076359

Comment: I just tried this solution. After I click the add post button, the code here runs four times but all before the new element has been added for the new post. So, the jQuery object is empty each time when it tries to select and focus it.

Comment: Yeah, this is a classic case of the problems associated with using one template's `onRendered` to modify the appearance of a sub-template. I've modified the answer to offer more ideas.

Comment: Ah, brilliant! I had used `setTimeout` to make it work, but this is much better. I did have to use `this.data._id` instead of `this._id`. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I'm glad it worked. :) Good call about `this.data` - I just fixed the answer.

Comment: Hi @DavidWeldon, no offence, I know you've too much of experience and knowledge. Can you please tell me or comment on my answer, why it will not work or In what cases my answer fails? Just want  to learn something.

Answer (score 1):

One option may be `observeChanges`? Can you try this?

in the rendered function do following

```
Template.postsAdmin.rendered = function(){

   var query = Posts.find({}); //your query
   var handle = query.observeChanges({
       added: function (id, user) {
          //code to set focus???
       }
   });
}
```

This code runs whenever there is a new item addeded to minimongo which matches your query.

Make sure to show the template after you load the data.

docs link http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe_changes

Comment: As per your request, here's my feedback: (1) `observeChanges` runs forever unless it's stopped or in an `autorun` - watch out for that (2) The observe isn't specific to this template - `Posts` could have changed somewhere else and this code will run (3) As mentioned in the 2nd half of my question, you still have a race condition where `added` could fire before the DOM element is added to the page.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, I need to go and stop my observers now :)